# Populate multiple text boxes based upon dropdown list selection in SharePoint 2013 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have 1 main list called **OnCallEscalationContacts**. This list has fields such as - **TechnologyTeam** [dropdown], **FirstContact** [people picker], **FirstContactPhone** [text field], **SecondContact** [people picker], SecondContactPhone [text field]

I have second list called **OnCall** which has fields such as - **TechnologyTeam** [dropdown], **FirstContact** [people picker], **FirstContactPhone** [text field], **SecondContact** [people picker], **SecondContact** [people picker], **SecondContactPhone** [text field].

When user picks an item from **OnCall** > **TechnologyTeam** the remaining fields in **OnCall** should be pre-populated from corresponding fields from  **OnCallEscalationContacts** fields.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Should the user be able to change the other fields in OnCall?

Comment: Yes they should be able to overwrite the entries in the fields

Comment: Resolved this using workflow